# JSF Tomcat container managed authentication plus additional login button

Tags: jsf, tomcat, authentication, container-managed

I am currently expanding my JSF website. I use Tomcat container managed authentication mechanism (works well, user is forced to login before accessing protected area), and now I want to provide an additional login button.

With the login button I want the user to get "LOGGED_IN_CUST" credentials in order that the web site provides additional features (like change / add / remove addresses) before reaching a secured page, like orderProducts.xhtml

Example:

Current site: index.xhtml
If I click the login link on the upper right side the login.xhtml page is displayed:

```
    <form action="j_security_check">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" bgcolor="#eff5fa" cellspacing="5"
            frame="box" styleClass="center">
            <h:outputLabel value="User name:" />
            <h:inputText id="j_username" tabindex="1" />
            <h:outputLabel value="Password:" />
            <h:inputSecret id="j_password" />
            <h:outputLabel value="" />
            <h:commandButton id="login" value="Login" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </form>
```

After using correct user credentials and pressing login button, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 400 - Invalid direct reference to form login page
message: Invalid direct reference to form login page
description: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

Is there a solution to log in by using an additional login link. And after the customer successfully logged in, the site which was displayed before is active again? (In this example index.xhtml)

Comment: Generally, tomcat doesn't like the `j_security_check` path being directly accessed by a control component or via a browser address bar. In my experience, both will cause what you're witnessing. `j_security_check` will automatically handle the redirect to the resource originally requested after successful authentication. By default, it sends users to the `<welcome/>` page. I've seen some reference to a certain `TextCallBackHandler` that might let you control the redirect URL, but documentation/samples of it on the web are scarce and poorly written. Look in the JAAS documentation for more

Comment: Many thanks! In this case, I think it's easier to remove the additional login link ;)

Comment: Just an other question because you mentioned the usage of j_security_check in combination with tomcat. Is the direct access of j_security_check possible by using an JEE Container like JBoss, GlassFish, Resin, etc ... ?

Comment: I don't imagine it'll be allowed on a full container either as they're  mostly based on tomcat and it's the same JAAS reference they're supposed to adhere to. I can't say for certain though as I've never tried to do it on a proper container like GF e.t.c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rebuilt the application. Instead of the login form with the action attribute `"j_security_check"` I created a conventional `commandButton` which calls the following doLogin method

```
public void doLogin(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context
            .getExternalContext().getRequest();

    try {
        // Try to login customer via container management
        request.login(eMail, password);

        /*
         * In case that the Login link was clicked, then the variable
         * "requestedURI" is null ! In that case we can redirect the
         * customer directly to his customerOverview site. A user with role
         * ADMIN will be redirected to systemInfo.xhtml and a user with role
         * CUST is redirected to customerOverview.xhtml.
         */
        if(requestedURI == null){
            if(request.isUserInRole(ROLE_ADMIN)){
                requestedURI = BASE_NAME+"/faces/sections/admin/systemInfo.xhtml";
            }
            else if(request.isUserInRole(ROLE_CUST)){
                requestedURI = BASE_NAME+"/faces/sections/customer/customerOverview.xhtml";
            }
            else{
                requestedURI = BASE_URL;
            }
        }

        /*
         * If everything worked well, redirect the customer to the desired
         * page
         */
        context.getExternalContext().redirect(requestedURI);
    } catch (ServletException se) {
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(Internationalization.getLoginFailed()));
    }
}
```

This solution works fine for me :)

Comment: Yes, this method isn't a part of the JEE standard. But this method provides the possibilities to:
1) Logon (using the servlet container)
2) Update the users last logon timestamp
3) Redirect user to the most appropriate site

And there is just one single method call necessary, invoked by clicking the login button. This was the most comfortable solution for me. Concerning your comment, I assume that there are other solutions to. Please let me know, how I can improve this. I will update the answer or accept your solution.

Comment: Just answer the question using only `java.*` or `javax.*` API from Java SE/EE so that it's useful for everyone. It's probably inside that `doLogin()` method of your homegrown class.

Comment: This is the whole part of the doLogin method. Other parts of this class arm't used by doLogin. So I really don't  know how to update this answer. Can you please provide such an approach.

Comment: I was referring to the method in the instance returned by `getServiceCustomer()`. None of those classes are part of standard Java. They are all 3rd party or even homegrown. So if one copypasted exactly this code, it would fail to compile. In other words, your answer is only applicable to **your specific environment** and to nobody else.